# Does Google app-indexing require minSdkVersion 9?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to integrate google's app indexing into my app. One of the steps is to include Google play services http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Setting up as seen in the link requires adding two lines:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'`

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

However when I add these lines, I get this error when I try to build:

`Error:Execution failed for task :MyApp:processDebugManifest.
 Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.`

After looking around on StackOverflow, I found that this is fixed by changing my minSdkVersion from 8 to 9.

Does this mean I have to use a min sdk of 9 for app indexing? Or is there another way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of [Google Play Services 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) (released back in October 2013):

> With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer platform versions, we’re dropping support for Froyo from this release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

This includes app indexing which were introduced in the recent [Google Play Services 5.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/07/google-play-services-5.html).